# Littlewood-Paley inequality in Tao's Lecture note

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Currently, I'm reading the proof of Lemma 3.2 in Tao's Lecture notes.
[https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/247b.1.07w/notes6.pdf](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Etao/247b.1.07w/notes6.pdf)

In this proof, a Littlewood-Paley decomposition is defined as $1 = \sum_{j} \psi_j^\color{red}{2}$.
However, at the end of the proof, the inequality

\begin{equation}
\| ( \sum_j |\psi_j(D)f|^2 )^{1/2} \|_{L^p} \lesssim \|f\|_{L^p}
\end{equation}

is used.
I have no idea to justify this inequality.

Comment: You are reading ahead of the proof of this inequality. Try a previous note

Comment: https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Etao/247b.1.07w/ Ctrl f for littlewood paley here

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thank you for your comment. I heard that Littlewood-Paley inequality hold even if $\sum_j \psi_j$ is not exactly $1$.

Comment: You may find this answer I wrote in this link a while back useful- [where to find a proof of LP theorem by Khintchine's inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1503538/where-to-find-a-proof-of-littlewood-paley-theorem-by-khintchines-inequality/3339694)